# Vectorization of pandas get_loc function

Tags: pandas, numpy

dfMain is a large dataframe, from which df1 was created based on certain conditions.The index for dfMain is a unique timestamp.

As the pandas.dataframe.index.get_loc function only takes one value at a time, can the following code be vectorized?

```
    df1 = dfMain[(dfMain['colX'] == 1) &
                            (dfMain['date_minute'].dt.time < pd.Timestamp('10:00').time())]

    # make a list containing the indices
    nextRow = []
    for row in df1.itertuples(index=True):
        nextRow.append(dfMain.index.get_loc(row.Index))

    # get the subsequent row
    nextRow = np.array(nextRow) + 1
```

I have tried numpy.where:

```
np.where(df1['date_minute'] == dfMain['date_minute'])
```

but that is throwing an error `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: No idea wat U r trying to do. Share a few rows, with expected output

Comment: You mean `df1.values`?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It should be pretty efficient, especially if the introduced  column `__` of type `RangeIndex` is never internally replaced with the actual integer array (which I can't verify)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3, 1, 2, 4, 5], 'col2': [23, 54, 53, 77, 12]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
hash_indices=['c', 'b', 'b', 'e']

df.assign(__=df.reset_index(drop=True).index)['__'].loc[hash_indices].to_numpy()
# array([2, 1, 1, 4])
```